# No matching signal for on_treeWidget_customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt5

I know that there were similar threads but what was suggested does not solve my problem.I am trying to build gui,for this software
https://geo-metronix.de/ocl/public.php?service=files&t=33c8b845889ad85ada285fe6db24b457

I have Gui,but in terminal I got:QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_treeWidget_customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)

Also in my Gui I got:
Can't open XML file for reading:/home/milenko/proc_mt/bin/db/database:xml:No such file or directory
Failed to open local database:out of memory Error opening database
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the former may happen on corrupted .ui files, just check for errors on .ui xml and the later needs more explanation about the file you're trying to load an how